# Should I skip SAS DI Studio?

Tags: sas, sas-dis

I work in an organization where we for many years have been planning to start using SAS DI Server/DIStudio.
Now we are just a few months away from starting to use the product. It's a huge investment. The license cost is just a minor part. Training and the project for converting current base programs to DI Studio Jobs is where the big money will be spent.

But now I'm beginning to have doubts.
DI Studio depends on SAS Metadata Server. And as I understand SAS Viya has no metadata server.
We are on a 100% 9.4 environment today, but we want to introduce SAS Viya. Using DI Studio means we have to keep two environments up and running and in sync (four when counting test environments). And what happens the day SAS9.4 is not supported? Will there be a migration path? Is there even a DI substitute for SAS Viya?

What do you say? Would you begin using SAS DI Studio today?
Or would you continue base-coding your DI-jobs and focus on migrating to SAS Viya and get rid of the 9.4 environment?

Comment: Post on communities.sas.com for better answers, this isn't a valid SO question.

Comment: Ooops. You're right. I should have read [the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before asking.

I'm just afraid to get a SAS sales person on the phone if post a question on communities.sas.com using my sas login...

Comment: Create a new account then....

Comment: Skip DI Studio.  Also - shameless plug - you might want to consider the SASjs framework for structuring your SAS jobs.   You can use it to deploy to both SAS 9 and Viya:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKfUHTngSFo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Reeza on forum but I would recommend moving forward to Viya vs DI Studio. If you plan on switching to Viya, no need to continue adding to the current stack. Just makes migration harder.